# Reference to finite coverings causing injections on deRham cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

So, I've heard that if you have a finite degree covering of a compact connected manifold by another compact connected manifold of dimension $n$ (So $\pi :M \rightarrow N$) gives an injection on the deRham cohomology for $1\leq k\leq n-1$ given by $\pi^{*}$.

I am looking for a proof of this, but I am not sure where to find it. I skimmed through Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds but did not find anything on the topic. I have heard that it has something to do with integration along fibres, but I am not sure.

Many Thanks!

Comment: it's enough to prove it for normal coverings. Use averaging by the automorphism group of the covering to make $\Omega(N)$ to a direct summand of $\Omega(M)$.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184529/cohomology-group-of-free-quotient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track. Since the fibers are finite in this case, saying "integration along the fibers" amounts to summing, or averaging, the preimages. In certain arenas, this is called the *trace* according to $\pi$.

Consider an open set $U\subset N$ that is evenly covered, and let $\phi_i\colon U\to U_i$ be (smooth) local inverses of $\pi$, $i=1,\dots,s$. Then for any closed $k$-form $\omega$ on $M$, we can consider the $k$-form on $N$ whose restriction to $U$ is given by
$$\pi_*\omega\big|_U = \frac1s\sum_{i=1}^s \phi_i^*\omega.$$
Now I'll leave it to you to check that

(1) $\pi_*\omega$ is well-defined.

(2) If $\omega = \pi^*\psi$, then $\pi_*\omega = \psi$.

(3) $d(\pi_*\omega)=\pi_*(d\omega) = 0$, so $\pi_*\colon H^k(M)\to H^k(N)$.

More generally, whenever a compact Lie group $G$ (in this case a finite one) acts on $M$, you can show that $H^*(M) \cong H^*_G(M)$, where the latter is the cohomology of the complex of $G$-invariant differential forms. Taking $G$ to be the group of deck-transformations, we get $H^*_G(M)\cong H^*(N)$. (All cohomology here is deRham, so isomorphic to singular cohomology with $\Bbb R$-coefficients.)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help!